# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (1,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a brute force approach for the knapsack problem, unfortunately when trying to graph the results I get this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (1,)

```
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def brute_force(values, weights, capacity):
    num_items = len(values)
    max_value = 0
    subset = []
    
    for i in range(2**num_items):
        current_value = 0
        current_weight = 0
        current_subset = []
        
        for j in range(num_items):
            if(i & (1 << j)) != 0:
                current_value += values[j]
                current_weight += weights[j]
                current_subset.append(j)
                
        if current_weight <= capacity and current_value > max_value:
            max_value = current_value
            subset = current_subset
            
    return max_value, subset

input_sizes = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
running_times = []
for size in input_sizes:
   values = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(size)]
   weights = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(size)]
   capacity = sum(weights) // 2

  start_time = time.time()
  max_value, subset = brute_force(values, weights, capacity)
  end_time = time.time()
  running_time = end_time - start_time
  running_times.append(running_time)

  print(f"Input size: {size}")
  print(f"Chosen subset: {subset}")
  print(f"Chosen weight: {sum(weights[i] for i in subset)}")
  print(f"Running time: {running_time: .6f} seconds")

  plt.plot(input_sizes, running_times, marker = 'o')
  plt.xlabel('Input size')
  plt.ylabel('Running time (s)')
  plt.title('Brute force Knapsack')
  plt.show()
```

Comment: your code is not reproducible. we don't know where you define `running_times` and `input_sizes`, which are the variables you use in plot. Please edit your question to post a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: Sorry, I added the top part now

Comment: the code gives me indentation error.  `values = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(size)]
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`  when running it

Comment: Sorry, when I copied it it moved everything inside for forwards but in the IDE the code is indented correctly, I edited the code here.

Comment: ok, now you are plotting inside the loop. You should plot outside the loop, when `running_times` has been populated with all the values and has a size of 5 elements. Put the plot outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plt` was inside the loop meaning that `running_times` has only one value whereas `input_sizes` has 5 values...

This should work:

```py
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def brute_force(values, weights, capacity):
    num_items = len(values)
    max_value = 0
    subset = []
    
    for i in range(2**num_items):
        current_value = 0
        current_weight = 0
        current_subset = []
        
        for j in range(num_items):
            if(i & (1 << j)) != 0:
                current_value += values[j]
                current_weight += weights[j]
                current_subset.append(j)
                
        if current_weight <= capacity and current_value > max_value:
            max_value = current_value
            subset = current_subset
            
    return max_value, subset

input_sizes = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
running_times = []
for size in input_sizes:
    values = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(size)]
    weights = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(size)]
    capacity = sum(weights) // 2

    start_time = time.time()
    max_value, subset = brute_force(values, weights, capacity)
    end_time = time.time()
    running_time = end_time - start_time
    running_times.append(running_time)

    print(f"Input size: {size}")
    print(f"Chosen subset: {subset}")
    print(f"Chosen weight: {sum(weights[i] for i in subset)}")
    print(f"Running time: {running_time: .6f} seconds")

plt.plot(input_sizes, running_times, marker = 'o')
plt.xlabel('Input size')
plt.ylabel('Running time (s)')
plt.title('Brute force Knapsack')
plt.show()
```

i reduced the `input_list` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (for speed, so you can put it back) and the output looks like this:

[image]